# How bad are Hardware_ECC_Recovered, Seek_Error_rate and Raw_read_error_rate for disks?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

As I bought a second-hand like-new 10TB disk on Amazon for back-up purposes, I did a smart read which showed the disk had barely been used.

The smart info was very confusing though, as Western Digital Red's have much easier to read smart disk info.

How bad could these errors potentially be?

[image]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some drives, the raw values should not be considered true literal values, rather they are a "combo field" collapsing various related informations. On these drives, an high ECC hardware recovery value or an high RAW error value should not be considered an indication of an imminent failure.

On these drivers, rather than the raw values, please consider the normalized ones (value/threshold/worst)

Anyway, it's a Seagate drive, right?

Comment: Yeah. Ironwolf Pro 10TB